# How do you show error messages in reactjs

Tags: relayjs

The onFailure callback on Relay store updates does not have access to good information about the error. It just has access to a generic `Error` instance where the error message from the server is hidden inside of the message surrounded by debugging information.

I want to show the error message that I got from the server in the UI.

How do I get access to it?

Answer (score 2):

Found out that you can get to the error from inside the `onFailure` callback like this: `transaction.getError().source.errors`

Comment: Since it's been 48 hours, you can now accept your own answer! http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer